# Twiiter Bootstrap - form dropdown dividers and headings

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Boostrap, I'm trying to create a form dropdown with dividers within the dropdown, corresponding to each section. Is that possible?

[JSFiddle included](http://jsfiddle.net/TDtSp/1/)

I'd like to create something like:

```
<!--GROUP-->
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<!--GROUP-->
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
```

Comment: have you tried optgroup?

Comment: Tried it, but without the indentation, which is the reason it did not work for me. I'll accept your answer, but it may be worthwhile noting for future readers that indentation matters.

Comment: Related post as an extension of this question for those using backbone.js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717366/backbone-marionette-passing-variable-to-composite-view-tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve this, you could use [`optgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/optgroup)

```
<div class="container">
    <select>
        <optgroup label="Group 1">
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group 2">
            <option>Item 1</option>
            <option>Item 2</option>
            <option>Item 3</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</diV>​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/M8pSH/